# Preventing line wrapping in CSS layouts

Tags: css, frontend

My CSS designer has made a design where there are two ul siblings laid out left to right.  The layout is done by specifying the width of the `ul` tags.

He is using Firefox on Windows where everything looks fine.  I am using Firefox on OS X where the contents of one of the `li` tags has too much text so it flows to another line.  The design was made with the intention that the text is on one line.

There are a couple considerations to make:

- I want the the `ul` tags to go left to right, not top to bottom
- I want the solution to be i18n friendly (translating the strings should not cause them to break into two lines)

If this is defined in pixels why does it appear differently in OS X compared to Windows even in the same browser?

Is there a general CSS solution that can prevent wrapping lines or prevent the page from looking different in respect to line wrapping between OS X and Windows?  Or is this a lost cause?

Comment: Looks to me like the designer has some work to do to deliver a cross browser design.

Comment: I would suggest floating the `<li>` elements left, and perhaps post some code or a link to the design so we could see what you're dealing with?

Answer (score 52):

Setting `white-space: nowrap` on the `ul`s will prevent the text from wrapping, ever, until a `<br />` is found. As much as I understand, the lists are already horizontal, but for completeness' sake, you can do it by making the `li` elements `display: inline` or `display: inline-block`. The `white-space: nowrap` will not work for `float`ed list items.

References:

- [the white-space CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/white-space)
- [cross-browser display: inline-block](http://foohack.com/2007/11/cross-browser-support-for-inline-block-styling/)

Comment: `Setting white-space: nowrap on the uls will prevent the text from wrapping, ever` that is a gem of info.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, that setting `width: auto;` for those elements, could fix it too.